# How do i prevent a mouse from sending input to DirectInput game?

Tags: c++, mouse, raw-input, setwindowshookex, directinput

This question was originally about how to trap mouse events, which i solved after a lot of research using SetWindowsHookEx with C++.
Problem is, its working for me on Windows, it works in applications, but it doesnt work in games. 
can somebody help me understand why the mouse hook doesnt work in some games? could it be possible all the games i tried use Raw Input? :S
(i tried Ibb&Obb, Fallout 4, Metro Last Light and some other titles)

Basically im asking: how is it possible to use a Mouse Hook to trap it globally in all the applications running?

thanks for the helpers.

**EDIT :** I found out that most games i play use DirectInput. guess the better question is: How can i intercept mouse messages in DirectInput and prevent them from being registered by the game? i want to be able to drag the mouse and it would have no effect on the game.

Comment: Sure, hooks can only work when an app uses the normal Windows notifications posted as messages.  Games don't.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Hans, you are my savior :D is there any way i can trap the mouse in a different method to prevent the game responding to my mouse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a lot of research i found out that, from what i understood, API Hooking (Microsoft Detours, API Hijack and more) is the only way to do it.
**Important note**: it doesnt help me much since API Hooking for games require DLL injection which will get you ***banned*** from Steam and other platforms.

Comment: API hooking and dll injection doesn't get you banned. Steam itself uses API hooking all over the place and inject its' DLL into non-Steam games, that's how it manages to show Steam overlay in non-Steam games. Also, there are a lot of good software that does both: dll injection and API hooking. More examples would be MSI Afterburner, Discord.